# How can I call associations on ActiveRecord::Result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have two models `City` and `State`. Below is association between city and state.

state.rb

```
has_many :cities
```

city.rb

```
belongs_to :state
```

I executed below query,

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
query = "select * from states"
@states = connection.exec_query(query);
```

Now I am iterating over,

```
@states.each do |s|
  s.cities # gives me an error because it is not an state object
end
```

I want it like,

```
state = State.last

cities = state.cities
```

How can I do this with `@states` while iterating over it using a loop?

Comment: it should be `query = "select * from states"`

Comment: sorry it is states already

Comment: I suppose you don't want to instantiate an actual model object?

Comment: Please post exact error log & result class/query you got for `@states`.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the ActiveRecord associations like this:

```
State.all.each { |state| state.cities }
```